# cannot import name 'TypeAliasType' from 'typing_extensions' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/typing_extensions.py)

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, google-colaboratory

I using elevenlab api for voice cloning in google colab. Here is my code

```
import elevenlabs

from elevenlabs import set_api_key

set_api_key("*****************")
```

It gives me this error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'TypeAliasType' from 'typing_extensions' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/typing_extensions.py

I have changed the version of typing_extensions but it does not work for me.

I have changed the version of typing_extension as gpt suggest me to change the version of it. But it was still not working. when I install the new version of typing_extention. Then it gives me this error:

> ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
> tensorflow-probability 0.22.0 requires typing-extensions<4.6.0, but you have typing-extensions 4.8.0 which is incompatible.

along with installation

Answer (score 1):

Today I faced the same issue while connecting MySQL with Python.(cannot import name 'TypeAlias' from 'typing_extensions' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/typing_extensions.py))

**I solved this using:**

```
pip install typing-extensions --upgrade
```

Give it a try!